# Where can I find a good index for Rashi?  Either online (preferably) or a sefer

Tags: torah-study, internet, jewish-books, rashi

Where can I find a good index for Rashi?  Either online (preferably) or a sefer....

Comment: What kind of index are you looking for? What are you hoping to accomplish with it?

Comment: For example:  look up where Rashi says: lashon yishmaeli.

Comment: Where can I find a good index for Rashi? Either online (preferably) or a sefer.

Answer (score 11):

A solution is to use the Chabad online Rashi commentary to fuel Google searches. First, type

```
site:http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/
```

and then add your search terms after typing a space. Example:

```
site:http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/ אחרון אחרון חביב
```

to find a Rashi from this week's parsha.

Answer (score 2):

You can search hundreds of books and dozens of commentaries on the [Bar Ilan Responsa program](http://www.responsa.co.il).